# How can I set a dataframe as a GoogleSheet worksheet using a GoogleSheet template using Drive API?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to create a Googlesheets file by using the create() method from pygsheets, using another Googlesheets file as a template for the first file, using Google Colab.

According to the documentation, this can be achieved by getting the spreadsheet resource, and passing it to the 'template' argument in pygsheet's create() method, as below:

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4')
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['1', '2', '3'],
                   'b' : ['1', '2', '3']})

#Install necessary packages into session
!pip install --upgrade --quiet gspread
!pip install --quiet gspread-pandas
!pip install --upgrade --quiet pygsheets

import google.auth
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()
import pygsheets
credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
gc = pygsheets.client.Client(credentials)

#get spreadsheet resource
sheet_template = (sheets_service.spreadsheets()
                    .get(spreadsheetId = [speadsheetId])
                    .execute())

sh = gc.create('sheet',
               template = sheet_template)

sheet = sh.worksheet_by_title('Sheet1')
#set range to filtered data
sheet.set_dataframe(df, start = 'A2')
```

However, the gc.create() method ignores the template argument when the dictionary response passed to it is invalid, meaning it fails silently.

The spreadsheet that is being created is not using the template from the Googlesheet I have specified.

Comment: if you do `print(sheet_template)` between assigning the variable and creating the Spreadsheet using pygsheets, what do you obtain? From pygsheets create method documentation: `The template can either be a spreadsheet resource or an instance of Spreadsheet. **In both cases undefined values will be ignored.**`

Comment: I get a dictionary in the format that cg.create() requires.  I would paste the whole thing here but a) it's too long and b) it has actual sheet ids in it

Comment: In case the argument you pass to it is not `None`, the `create` method call should either properly create the sheet or return an exception if the argument passed is not valid. Have you checked the issues in the github page of the library? Perhaps you could consider publishing a new one related to this issue, if no similar ones can be found..

Comment: @carlesgg97 - Okay, thanks for the advice, I've added an issue on the pygsheets github page.